# Get all child categories in relationships laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5.1

There is a table id|title|pid.
How to get all of the child categories "recursive" using relationships in Laravel 5.1.

Created child relations

```
/**
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
 */
public function child() {
    return $this->hasMany(self::class, 'pid', 'id');
}
```

Now you need to run recursively and get all of the child categories in all categories.

Thanks.

Comment: I think I have the answer for this, but I'd like to see more detail to answer this perfectly

Comment: Thank you, I need to get "all" child resources of a certain category, recursively

Comment: What is the result you need? Just list of categories with their children? Or something more sophisticated?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you're talking about is something called `Nested Sets`.

https://github.com/etrepat/baum is a pretty decent package for this sort of thing.

Hope this helps!